# Confusion with assigning the value

Tags: java

Is there a difference between the following two :

```
ArrayList list = getData();

public ArrayList getData(){
    return otherList;
}
```

and

```
ArrayList list = someOtherArrayList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList list = someOtherArrayList;
```

In this case directly address of someOtherArrayList is assigned to list.

```
ArrayList list = getData();

public ArrayList getData() {   
    return otherList;
}
```

In this case, address of list returned is copied into temporary variable and later temporary variable to list. Here address copied in temporary variable because : When function returns, all its data on stack is deallocated/deleted, so otherList object reference is also deleted. But before that it is reference/address is copied into temporary variable. When address from temporary variable is copied in list variable. It is also deleted.

Comment: Why do you think `otherList` is deallocated on exit? It is not a local variable inside that method. It appears to be a member field of the class.

Comment: Yes rite..It is member field of a class.

Comment: @GrahamBorland : object reference is deleted, if list is locally created and returned. But if it is class field, then it's reference is returned but same above explained.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. In both cases you are assigning to `list` a reference to an existing `ArrayList`.

Comment: Edit the code to make this clearer. Change the name of one of them. :)

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

No. List is just **reference** to the object in memory.
It means that if you do:

```
list1 = list2;
list1.add("abc");
```

`list2.get(list2.size()-1)` will be "abc" also.

In method you return the same reference, so it behaves the same. If you return **copy** of list in method, then two approaches different.

Answer (score 0):

That's very strange :

```
ArrayList list = getData();

public ArrayList getData(){
    return list;
}
```

You're setting list to its own value, that is initially `null`.

So if `someotherlist` isn't null, there is a difference as you 1 does nothing.

**EDIT :** seen your edit. Now both assignements are identical. There is no difference. We could argue that one of them could be a little slower as a function is called but in this case it would be fastly inlined by the JIT compiler.